# «Ассоциируются со словом кризис» — стоит ли кавычить «кризис»?

Tags: кавычки

*В дуэли двух команд, которые в последнее время ассоциируются со словом кризис, симферопольцы на родном поле оказались сильнее...*

Стоит ли кавычить «кризис»? Рядом просто слово «слово».

Answer (score 2):

Слово *кризис* нужно как-то выделить, конечно. Можно использовать любой стандартный способ выделения, в том числе кавычками.

И я бы сказал "каждая из которых" вместо "которые".

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть подобное  оформление на Грамоте.ру, то там используется **курсив** (кавычки – это многофункциональный знак, который лишний раз лучше не применять).

Примеры:

Вопрос № 283026.     Слово ***рога***  в этом значении – разговорное.

Вопрос № 279272. Сочетание ***личный кабинет*** пишется строчными буквами...

**А стоит ли вообще как-то выделять слово  *кризис*?**

Например, в похожем сочетании *дерево берёза* (приложение + существительное) мы никак не выделяем слово *берёза*.

Но всё дело в том, что при отсутствии выделения нам **нужно будет склонять** слово *кризис*, а кавычки или курсив освобождают нас от такой необходимости (слово *кризис* может иметь форму И.п.).